# javascript function doesn't call in internal page on link click yii CListView

Tags: javascript, yii, clistview

i am using CListView in my one of form.
i used CHtml::link in one of column.
 and its html is like this

```
<a class="text-dark" value="31" href="javascript:void(0)" title="You received a new message">
```

and onclick of this link i called one javascript function

following function

```
 $('a.text-dark').click(function()
    {

        var id = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/mailbox/message/View') ?>/id/'+id,
                        success:function(data){ 

                                   },
                        error:function(data){ 
                                        alert('Your data has not been submitted..Please try again');
                                          }

          });
    });
```

My main issue is on first page it works perfect. function is called perfectly. but whenever i  click on next button from pagination and click on this link. function is not called. Except One page any page doesn't call function. What is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because that is a new element and therefore the applied function should be applied again, or simple solution

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.text-dark', function(){

   // do the job here
});
```

or add a function to your grid view and call it in after ajax update

```
 'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(){ here do stuff }'
```